# What's the best way to handle ResponseEntity on UI side?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have user's page where I have to show all posts which were writing by him and his friends after the page loading. What's the easiest way to do this on UI side? I'm using Thymeleaf + Spring.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/getBasicPosts")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getUSerAndFriendsPosts(String userId) {
        List<Post> postList;
        try {
            postList = postService.getUserAndFriendsPosts(Long.valueOf(userId));
        } catch (Exception otherExc) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(otherExc.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(postList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Probably easier to put the list into a modelAttribute than to return Json data. Full example here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

Answer (score 0):

Wenn you use Thymeleaf + Spring, your controllers have to return the path of the thymeleaf template:

```
   @RequestMapping("/getBasicPosts/{userId}")
   public String showBasicPosts(Model model, @PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
      Object obj = getUSerAndFriendsPosts(String userId).getBody();  
      model.addAttribute("obj", obj);
      return "path/of/template";
   }

   private ResponseEntity<Object> getUSerAndFriendsPosts(String userId) {
      List<Post> postList;
      try {
         postList = postService.getUserAndFriendsPosts(Long.valueOf(userId));
      } catch (Exception otherExc) {
         return new ResponseEntity<>(otherExc.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      }
      return new ResponseEntity<>(postList, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

and of course you should add a few properties to tell Spring about the location of Thymeleaf templates:

```
@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf Template Resolver")
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf Template Engine")
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
    return templateEngine;
}
```